# Having issues mounting disks from script

Tags: shell-script, systemd, mount, systemd-mount

I have a script that is triggered by udev rules that is partitioning the newly added disk and it creates a systemd unit file for it and supposed to mount it. However the mount part does not seam to work and it fails with some errors like: `A dependency job for mnt-volume1.mount failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.` even tried to mount it with mount command it runs without any error but when checking outside the script the partition is not mounted. If I run the systemd start manually everything works without any issues.

The udev triggered script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
LOGFILE=/tmp/set-bash.log
exec > >(tee -a $LOGFILE)
exec 2>&1

device=$1
dev=${device##*/}
FS=''

[ ${dev:0:2} = "sd" ] && FS='xfs' 
[ ${dev:0:2} = "vd" ] && FS='ext4' 

[ -z "${FS}" ] && { echo "No FS specified!"; exit ; }

[ -e "${device}1" ] || {

echo ';' | sfdisk ${device}

counter=0
while true
do
        [ "${counter}" = "60" ] && { echo "Timeout reached, exiting..."; exit; }
        [ -e "${device}1" ] && { 
        /usr/sbin/mkfs.${FS} ${device}1
        break
    }
    counter=$(( counter++))
    sleep 1
done
}

for i in {1..9999}
do
  if [[ ! -e "/mnt/volume${i}" ]]
  then
    declare -g DIRECTORY="volume${i}"
    mkdir -p /mnt/$DIRECTORY
    break
  fi
done


cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/mnt-${DIRECTORY}.mount
[Unit]
Description=mounting /mnt/${DIRECTORY}

[Mount]
What=${device}1
Where=/mnt/${DIRECTORY}
Type=${FS}
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl enable mnt-${DIRECTORY}.mount
systemctl start mnt-${DIRECTORY}.mount
```

The output of the script on the mounting part can be seen here:

```
+ systemctl daemon-reload
+ systemctl enable mnt-vpsie33.mount
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mnt-vpsie33.mount → /etc/systemd/system/mnt-vpsie33.mount.
+ systemctl start mnt-vpsie33.mount
A dependency job for mnt-vpsie33.mount failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Any way to have that done?

Comment: The two `exec` lines can be replaced with `exec >>"$LOGFILE" 2>&1`. The line `couter=$(( counter++))` fortunately has a typo, otherwise you would be incrementing `counter` by one, _and_ then assigning the previous value of `counter` back to itself thereby making the increment a no-op. The `{1..9999}` expands out to a list before the command is further processed; it would probably be better to use a counted loop here `for((i=1; i<=9999; i++))`

Comment: The information is well taken but it's not the point. It has nothing to do with the issue in hand.

Comment: None whatsoever, agreed, which is why I've left it as a comment. I can remove it as soon as you like.